# Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two UmRet operands

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm working on integrating an IDTech swiper into my app and I've gotten pretty far along, added the library, registered notifications, unregistered them, and now I'm working on a function that connects the reader. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here when I'm attempting to switch cases based on a return value.. could someone please help me?

```
func displayUmRet(operation: String, returnValue: UmRet) {

        var string = ""

    do {
        switch returnValue {

        case UMRET_SUCCESS: string = ""
        case UMRET_NO_READER: string="No reader attached"
        case UMRET_SDK_BUSY: string="Communication with reader in progress"
        case UMRET_MONO_AUDIO: string="Mono audio enabled"
            case UMRET_ALREADY_CONNECTED: string="Already connected"
            case UMRET_LOW_VOLUME: string="Low volume"
            case UMRET_NOT_CONNECTED: string="Not connected"
            case UMRET_NOT_APPLICABLE: string="Not applicable to reader type"
            case UMRET_INVALID_ARG: string="Invalid argument"
            case UMRET_UF_INVALID_STR: string="Invalid firmware update string"
            case UMRET_UF_NO_FILE: string="Firmware file not found"
            case UMRET_UF_INVALID_FILE: string="Invalid firmware file"
            default: string="<unknown code>"
        }
    } while (0)

   // var retStatus = UMRET_SUCCESS==ret

    //self.textResponse.text = "\(operation), \(retStatus), \(string)"

    self.hexResponse.text = "";


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a `.` before your cases:

```
enum UmRet {
  case UMRET_SUCCESS, UMRET_FAILURE
}

var string = " "

let returnValue = UmRet.UMRET_SUCCESS

switch returnValue {
case .UMRET_SUCCESS: string = "y"
case .UMRET_FAILURE: string = "n"
}
```

Also, `0` isn't the same as `false` in Swift, so:

```
do {
...
} while (0)
```

Shouldn't work either.

And you don't need semicolons at the end of a line, so this:

```
self.hexResponse.text = "";
```

can be this:

```
self.hexResponse.text = ""
```

And finally, if your switch statement has every case for every case in your enum, you don't need a default case. (that's why mine didn't have one in the example)

By the way, `~=` is just the operator for the pattern-matching function, which is what Swift does in a switch statement. It works kind of like the `==` function, for instance, `Int ~= Int` is the same as `Int == Int`. But it's a bit more versatile: for instance `Range ~= Int`, eg `0...3 ~= 2` returns whether or not the `Int` is in the range. (So true in this case) For enums, it matches cases to cases. In my example, it'll match `UMRET_SUCCESS`, and `string` will be set to `y`.